# Are inverse morphisms given for every category in category theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have been studying briefly the Omega algebra category and I’m trying to understand how isomorphism makes sense of the morphisms in the standard commutative diagram:

[image: omegaalgebraincategorytheory]

My question is: is ${f^{n_i}}^{-1} \circ \omega_i^{-1}$ the isomorphism proving $X \cong \hat{X}^{n_i}$?

Edit:
I am trying to ask essentially two questions:

1. Does a given category contain inverse morphisms?
2. Are inverse morphisms always like or similar to isomorphisms?

I’m pretty confused about the entire situation with omega algebras but not the other examples in the book.

Comment: Please provide more context. E.g. what are the exact conditions, from which category the above arrows are coming, what is $\omega_i$, which arrows are supposed to be isomorphism, etc?

Comment: The question comes from the book Abstract and Concrete Categories: the Joy of Cats. I made the question after reading chapter I, section 3.3. Let me try to provide more context if this isn’t sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An isomorphism would be a function $f\colon X\to\hat X$ that is

1. an $\Omega$-homomorphism, i.e. satisfying $\hat w_i\circ f^{n_i}=f\circ\omega_i$
2. there exists a function $g\colon\hat X\to X$ that is an $\Omega$-homomorphism such that $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_{\hat X}$ and $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X$.

In particular, an isomorphism of $\Omega$-algerbas is an isomorphism $f\colon X\to\hat X$ of sets for which both it and its inverse $f^{-1}\colon\hat X\to X$ are $\Omega$-homomorphisms, i.e. both  $\hat w_i\circ f^{n_i}=f\circ\omega_i$ and $\omega_i\circ (f^{-1})^{n_i}=f^{-1}\circ\hat\omega_i$.

Comment: This finally makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.goodmath.org/blog/2019/02/20/category-theory-lesson-2-basics-of-categorical-abstraction/,

The answer seems to be that morphisms have three classifications by default and, looking at the diagram, an isomorphism does not exist to show the aforementioned isomorphism equation to be true.

More specifically, the arrows are pointed in a specific direction. This leads to a specific isomorphism between two objects. It isn’t the one I thought. It’s $X^{n_i} \cong \hat{X}$ (I was reading the diagram arrows backwards).